# How to change table and sequence owner to another user with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, owner

Created these tables and sequences under `postgres` user:

table creation schema

```
SET search_path TO main;
CREATE TABLE table1 ...
CREATE TABLE table2 ...
CREATE TABLE table3 ...
```

sequence creation schema

```
CREATE SEQUENCE main.seq1...
CREATE SEQUENCE main.seq2...
CREATE SEQUENCE main.seq3...
```

Now want to change all of them to an another owner named `user1`. How to do without recreate these objects as they are been using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE/SEQUENCE objectname OWNER TO somerole;
```

You can only execute that as a superuser or as a role what is member of both the old and new owning role.

If you want to do that for many tables at the same time, use `format` to generate a script:

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE %I OWNER TO somerole;',
          oid::regclass
       )
FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'table%';
```

Then execute that script. If you are using `psql`, you can use `\gexec` to do that in one statement:

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE %I OWNER TO somerole;',
          oid::regclass
       )
FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'table%' \gexec
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have many tables, how to do it in batch? All the objects are in the main schema.